# ffmpeg keyframe extraction

Tags: ffmpeg, keyframe

I have been trying to extract keyframes from video using ffmpeg 0.11.1 . So far all the commands I have tried do not extract keyframes but return all the frames ie 25fps*total time number of frames in the output. 
I tried setting the keyint_min as 25 to make sure there is a amximum of 1 keyframe per second.

```
ffmpeg -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -i C:\test.mp4 -vsync 2 -f image2 C:\testTemp\thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

But still all the frames are returned.

Then i tried, to separate the keyframes by 20 seconds.

```
ffmpeg -i C:\test.mp4 -vf select='eq(pict_type\,I)*(isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,20))' -vsync 0 -f image2 C:\testTemp\%09d.jpg
```

Again same result, all the frames are returned.

What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your first command you are using the filter as an input option. I don't know how ffmpeg will interpret that.

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\test.mp4 -vf select='eq(pict_type\,I)',setpts='N/(25*TB)' C:\testTemp\%09d.jpg
```

Change `25` to the frame rate of your source: 30000/1001 for NTSC video, 24000/1001 for NTSC film, 25 for PAL, etc.

Control output quality with the `-q:v` or `-qscale:v` option (just called `-qscale` in old ffmpeg). Range for mpeg* is 1-31 where 31 is the worst quality.

Next time remember that ffmpeg usage questions are to be asked at superuser.com since stackoverflow is specifically for programming.

Comment: Hi thanks, but I got an error Error initializing filter select with args. The number of opening and closing ' are not equal so I tried changing the select part to select='eq(pict_type\,I),setpts=N/(25*TB)' & then select='eq(pict_type\,I),setpts='N/(25*TB)'' But both returned the same error

Comment: Sorry. Bad paste job. I updated the command, but I am unable to test at this time.

Comment: I am getting: Missing ')' or too many args in 'eq(pict_type\,I)' and then another error as error while parsing expression 'eq(pict_type\,I)'

Comment: For the record, the command works for me on OS X with 0.11.1. /cc @shi

Comment: I am using Windows 8 RP. I looked up http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-November/003266.html and realized that if I don't write '\' in eq(pict_type\,I) i.e. I write eq(pict_type,I) it works like a charm!